# Seaborn - Logarithmic scaling of the "z axis" in a bivariate KDE plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am currently plotting some data using Seaborn's `JointPlot`:

```
pitch = pd.Series(angles[:, 0], name="Pitch")
roll = pd.Series(angles[:, 1], name="Roll")
plot = sns.jointplot(pitch, roll, kind="kde", space=0.3)
```

[image: KDE Plot]

What I would like to be able to use log scaling in the "z axis" of this plot. That is, neither in the pitch or roll dimension of this plot, but in the "density of data points" dimension. Is there a way to do this using the KDE plot? Or because the KDE is just performing a fitting to the data, can it not be scaled in this way?

Feel free to explain only for the `kdeplot` function instead of for `JointPlot` if that's simpler.

Comment: You basically want to do [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_log.html) via the `joint_kws` parameter. Though I think that if you are going to logscale the contour plot you should logscale the marginals too, using @Serenity's method.

Comment: @golmschenk, one method would be simply take the logs of the value, store the result in the dataframe, and then pass that with an appropriate label to seaborn

Comment: @PaulH, the values I want the log of are those of the KDE curve that was fit to the data. How would I get those values initially to calculate the log from? Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to compute the KDE yourself.